# How to use Libmms functions

Tags: iphone, xcode, stream, ffmpeg, mms

I am looking for an example of how to use the libmms and ffmpeg to stream a mms audio ? Now i have imported both libraries on my xcode project, and i think the 1st thing to do is call mms_connect(), but i dont know what arguments to use.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

- You can use:

mms_connect(NULL, NULL, g_tcUrl.av_val, g_hostname.av_val, g_playpath.av_val, "", g_port, 128*1024)

Note:

```
NSString* strTemp;      
strTemp = @"mms://123.30.49.85/htv2";
// strTemp = @"mms://212.58.251.92/wms/bbc_ami/radio1/radio1_bb_live_int_eq1_sl0";
g_tcUrl.av_val = new char[[strTemp length] + 1];
[strTemp getCString:g_tcUrl.av_val
          maxLength:([strTemp length]+1)
           encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
g_tcUrl.av_len = strlen(g_tcUrl.av_val);
//strTemp = @"212.58.251.92";
strTemp = @"123.30.49.85";
g_hostname.av_val = new char[[strTemp length]+1];       
[strTemp getCString:g_hostname.av_val
          maxLength:([strTemp length]+1)
           encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
g_hostname.av_len = strlen(g_hostname.av_val);
//strTemp = @"/wms/bbc_ami/radio1/radio1_bb_live_int_eq1_sl0";
strTemp = @"/htv2";
g_playpath.av_val = new char[[strTemp length] + 1];         
[strTemp getCString:g_playpath.av_val
          maxLength:([strTemp length]+1)
           encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
g_playpath.av_len = strlen(g_playpath.av_val);
g_port = 1755;
```